# WP & Nginx: redirect post URLs containing '/folder/' but not image URLs containing '/folder/'

Tags: wordpress, image, redirect, nginx

On a Wordpress / Nginx site, I am removing / redirecting a section of articles from our website, and would like to redirect all urls of this content to another section of the site.

I've got this much working just great (see below), but unfortunately the name of an image folder also contains the string I'm using to catch the redirect.

We want for these images to show still. Here are a few example URLs of the desired behavior I'm trying to achieve:

1. http://www.website.com/contenttoberemoved/
   -- redirect to http://www.website.com/other/section/
2. http://www.website.com/contenttoberemoved/an-article/
   -- redirect to http://www.website.com/other/section/
3. http://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/custom/contenttoberemoved/images/image-name.jpg
   -- perform NO redirect

And here is the current Nginx configuration:

```
# Addresses URL #1 above
    if ( $request_filename ~ contenttoberemoved/ ) {
        rewrite ^(.*) http://www.website.com/category/articles/ permanent;
    }

# Addresses thousands of URLs with the structure of #2 above
    if ( $request_filename ~ contenttoberemoved/.+ ) {
        rewrite ^(.*) http://www.website.com/category/articles/ permanent;
}

# No idea what to do to address #3
```

Here is the full server block:

```
server {
    server_name website.com www.website.com;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # redirects

        if ( $request_filename ~ contenttoberemoved/ ) {
            rewrite ^(.*) http://www.website.com/category/articles/ permanent;
        }
        if ( $request_filename ~ contenttoberemoved/.+ ) {
            rewrite ^(.*) http://www.website.com/category/articles/ permanent;
        }

    #many page-level redirects below....
}
```

How can I make the redirect instructions broad enough to encompass example URLs #1 & #2 above, but specific enough to not include images (or really anything other than the posts I'm trying to target)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your URLs there is no need to use `if` and regexps. Simple `location` will be enough:

```
location ^~ /contenttoberemoved/ {
    return 301 /category/articles/;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Hi Alexey, this works for only URL example #2 above (a post at www.website.com/contenttoberemoved/an-article/), it doesn't redirect the page www.website.com/contenttoberemoved/, or avoid redirecting images whose paths contain /contenttoberemoved/.

Comment: Ok, question updated with full server block. I had changed it to include your suggestion, but for clarity / consistency of the original question I changed it back to what I originally had.

Comment: Are "many page-level redirects" similar to original `if`s? Probably they somehow match your url #3.

Comment: Are you sure you visited `/contenttoberemoved/` and not `/contenttoberemoved` (without trailing slash)?

Comment: Got it working using your update, I had made a mistake previously. Thanks for the help Alexey!

Comment: Also I would recommend to take a look at http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil and http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls and get rid of `if`s as much as possible.

Comment: Those were the only if s in my block, so should be good to go, but thanks for the reminder!